# Xilinx FFT IP core simulation test bench in VHDL

Tags: fft, vhdl, xilinx

I'm trying to use an FFT IP core on a spartan-3A FPGA board and for simulation. I'm not getting the expected results!

Here is my test bench which doesn't give me the output I want, it just returns 0s for output while the "dv" signal returns '1'!
P.S. first I'm trying to test a 16 ifft core to see if it works or not.

```
-- TestBench Template 

  LIBRARY ieee;    
  USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;      
  USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;      
  use std.textio.all;      
  -- use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;     
  -- use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;


  library STD;
  use STD.textio;


    ENTITY testfft16 IS
    END testfft16;

    ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testfft16 IS 

    -- Component Declaration    
      COMPONENT tt16       
      port(        
      clk    : in STD_LOGIC;      
      start  : in STD_LOGIC;         
      unload : in STD_LOGIC;       
      fwd_inv    : in STD_LOGIC;      
      fwd_inv_we : in STD_LOGIC;      
      rfd   : out STD_LOGIC;      
      busy  : out STD_LOGIC;      
      edone : out STD_LOGIC;      
      done  : out STD_LOGIC;       
      dv    : out STD_LOGIC;      
      xn_re : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );     
      xn_im : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );        
      xn_index : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );      
      xk_index : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );      
      xk_re : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );      
      xk_im : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 )     
         );    
      END COMPONENT;     


--inputs
signal clk :  STD_LOGIC  :='0'; 
Signal start :  STD_LOGIC  :='1'; 
Signal unload :  STD_LOGIC  :='0'; 
Signal fwd_inv : STD_LOGIC  :='0'; 
Signal fwd_inv_we : STD_LOGIC  :='0';
 Signal xn_re :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ) := "00000000000000000000000000000011"; 
Signal xn_im :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ) := (others => '0'); 

 --outputs
Signal rfd   :   STD_LOGIC; 
Signal busy  :  STD_LOGIC; 
Signal edone :  STD_LOGIC; 
Signal done :       STD_LOGIC; 
Signal dv   :       STD_LOGIC; 
Signal xn_index :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 ); 
Signal xk_index :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 ); 
Signal xk_re :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ); 
Signal xk_im :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );






--constant  declaration 
constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;



    BEGIN

    -- Component Instantiation
      uut: tt16 
       PORT MAP(
      clk , start , unload , fwd_inv , fwd_inv_we ,rfd , busy , edone , done                           ,dv , xn_re , xn_im ,
       xn_index , xk_index , xk_re , xk_im );


 --Clock process definitions
 clk_process :process
 begin
 clk <= '0';
 wait for clk_period/2;
 clk <= '1';
 wait for clk_period/2;
 end process;



    --  Test Bench Statements
 tb : PROCESS

       BEGIN
         start <='1';
       unload <='0';
        fwd_inv <='0'; 
       fwd_inv_we <='1';

  wait for clk_period;
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period;
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period;
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000001111";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000011100001";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000001110000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000010";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000010";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000011110000000000110";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000011110000000000010";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000001111100000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
   wait for clk_period; 
  xn_re <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
  xn_im <= "00000000000000000000000000000111";

  unload <= '1';
  start <= '0';

        wait; -- will wait forever
       END PROCESS tb;
    --  End Test Bench 

    END;
```

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if you used hex literals for your values instead of binary (and easier still if you used numeric literals and convert/typecast). Also, should `start` really be asserted for the entire data stream, or just pulsed for one clock cycle at the beginning?

Comment: Without having your `tt16` component, you're either operating the model incorrectly or it doesn't work.  Without knowing how you're model was configured there may be guess work involved. (This appears to be a streaming I/O model, a single port, the port signals described in [DS260](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/xfft_ds260.pdf) Core Symbol and Port Definitions, starting on P. 10. See Figure 8. Timing for Continuous Streaming Data, P.27. )

Comment: @DavidKoontz  
Actually it's a Burst I/O Radix-2 architecture 16 point fft and i had a look on the DS260 LogiCORE IP Fast Fourier Transform v7.1 and my simulation results were the same as page33 Figure 14 but the output. here are my simulation images: [The Loading Part](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x74hxlyyb0w2sgv/11.JPG?dl=0) [The Unloading Part](https://www.dropbox.com/s/85yxezrttvb6cgp/12.JPG?dl=0).

Comment: @fru1tbat The START is asserted to begin the 
data loading and transform calculation (for the Burst I/O 
architectures) and it's active high so it's '1' during the loading period.

Comment: Are you sure? "Begin the data loading" and "'1' during the loading period" are not necessarily the same thing. Just make sure you're not supposed to pulse it before or during the first sample only.

Comment: @fru1tbat It works the same with a pulse!